# Why do people run virtual machines on an NAS?

Tags: virtual-machine, nas

I just heard that some people run VMs on their NAS... so does the VM run on the NAS's processor and how does it send the whole desktop's video to your Mac or PC that you are using?

I read one article saying you can test new OS... but I wonder why not just install VirtualBox on your Mac and run the VM occasionally?  Why run it so far away on an NAS and it could slow down your NAS which make video streaming not so smooth? (the NAS doesn't have a powerful processor to begin with, unlike your Mac or PC).

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions. VMs can be used for many things, not only running desktops. The main reason to run VMs (or containers for that matter) on NASs is that a NAS is an (often reasonably powerful) always-on device that can run services in a network that need to be available continuously.

Comment: So much for assumptions: A NAS **can** be a always-on device but doesn't have to be. ;-)

Comment: @StarCat I am not "accusing". I am sure if people do it, there are good reasons.  But seems like the downvoters and you are accusing me

Comment: I am not accusing you. I am challenging your assumptions. That's something very different. This is one of the reasons "Why is (such and such)?" questions do not work here,

Comment: @bey0nd, Of course you're completely correct ;-). Let's just say that, in general, a NAS is an always-on device or at least (usually) designed and marketed like one.

Answer (score 1):

Software products can end up with featuritis when they need to have new features to sell back into the same user base, but there are some good use cases.

For example, if a home has only laptops and mobile devices, they are not running all the time. The NAS is always running.

This also allows you to customize the NAS. Having a way to run services not built into the box is in theme with providing other services such as printing, file saving, music streaming. If you don't like the streaming service that came with the box, you can add your own and it will always be on.